# How to I pass a object ID saved in one view to another view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails to build an app as follows. I want to create a Load with multiple stops. I have a class Load with "has_many :stops". Once the load structure is created I save the load and take the user to new stop view. How do I take the load Id that was created in the last click and pass it on to the stop? Here is what I have in new stop.

```
<%= label_tag :load_id %><br />
<%= number_field_tag :load_id %>
```

Comment: May be watching this railscasts episode will give you ideas on how to solve your problem: http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms

Comment: Do you have any controller code?

Comment: To generalize, here is what I am trying to do. I create Model A  and submit button redirects me to Model B. I want Model A data that was saved to be available in Model B.

Comment: 1.Why you are not using relationship. Using relationship you could easily acces Model A data into Model B.
2. You can't redirect data directly from Model A to Model B using submit button. There should be controller action involved in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a nested resource, so the load_id will be in the URL: `/loads/:load_id/stops/new`.

In the Load model:

```
class Load < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stops
end
```

Routes:

```
resources :loads do
  resources :stops
end
```

Controller for stops:

```
class StopsController < ApplicationController
  # get /loads/:load_id/stops/new
  def new
    load = Load.find(params[:load_id])
    @stop = load.stops.build
  end
  # post /loads/:load_id/stops
  def create
    load = Load.find(params[:load_id])
    @stop = load.stops.create(params[:stop])
    if @stop.save
      format.html { redirect_to([@stop.post, @stop], :notice => 'Stop was successfully created.') }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

Extracted from here:

http://blog.8thcolor.com/2011/08/nested-resources-with-independent-views-in-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: def create
   -
   -
    if @load.save
      p = Load.find(params["id"])
      redirect_to '/loads/p/stops/new'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

Comment: Yes, but the code is bad. _def create; @load = Load.new(params[:load]); if @load.save; redirect_to new_load_post(@load); else; render 'new'; end_